# Getting wrong values when calculating average values of an Array in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, multidimensional-array, floating-point

I am trying to read the values of a Matrix stored in a file, then calculate the average of each column.

This is my output:

```
3.000000        -965.000000     3.000000        -1111.000000    -585.000000
2.000000        -337.000000     2.000000        -649.000000     687.000000
3.000000        922.000000      3.000000        -1160.000000    -699.000000
4.000000        -837.000000     4.000000        -283.000000     -1696.000000
2.400000        -389.000000     2.400000        -449.000000     -1237.000000


Averages:
-531.000000     -59.000000      -186.200000     -561.600000     -414.040000
```

Array size is calculated from the amount of data in the file by the function "numOfLines".
The matrix is read correctly from file, but the calculation seems to be wrong somehow.

Any insight on the cause of this problem would be greatly appreciated.

PS: I am new to C programming.

```
int numOfLines(FILE* Matrixfile) 
{ 
    int c, count;
    count = 0;
    for (;; ) {
        c = fgetc(Matrixfile);
        if (c == EOF)
            break;          

        if (c == '\n')
            ++count;        // end of line => increment line counter
    }
    rewind(Matrixfile);

    return count;
}

int main()
{
    FILE* Matrixfile;
    Matrixfile = fopen("dataread.txt", "r");
    if (Matrixfile == NULL)
        return 1;

    int Msize = numOfLines(Matrixfile);

    printf("%d\n\n", Msize);

    
    // Reading text file into 2D array
    int i, j;

    //Allocating array
    double** Matrix2;
    Matrix2 = (double**)calloc(Msize, sizeof(double*));
    for (int i = 0; i < Msize; i++)
        Matrix2[i] = (double*)calloc(Msize, sizeof(double));
    

    for (i = 0; i < Msize; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < Msize; j++) {
            fscanf(Matrixfile, "%lf", &Matrix2[i][j]);
        }

        char eol;                         // dummy variable
        fscanf(Matrixfile, "%c", &eol);     // read \n character
    }

    double* Averages;
    Averages = (double*)calloc(Msize, sizeof(double));

    //calculation done here

    for (i = 0; i < Msize; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < Msize; j++) {
            printf("%lf\t", Matrix2[i][j]);
            Averages[i] = Averages [i] + Matrix2[i][j]/Msize;
            if (j == Msize - 1)
                printf("\n");
        }
        
        //putc('\n', stdout);                 
    }
    printf("\n\nAverages:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < Msize; i++)
        printf("%lf\t", Averages[i]);
    
    fclose(Matrixfile);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're calculating the "horizontal averages" (`(3-965+3-1111-585)/5`), not "vertical averages" (`(3+2+3+4+2)/5`)

Comment: You also seem to be assuming that the number of columns is the same as the number of rows. Your file has 5 lines but 6 columns, so you're writing outside the array bounds for each row.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out... I feel silly. I just switched i and j in "Matrix2[i][j]/Msize;"
Also the the problem I am solving involves NxN matrices of unknown size.
Anyway thank a lot.

Comment: Unrelated: you could try optimizating the number of divisions (`1/N + 2/N + 3/N + ...` vs `(1 + 2 + 3 + ...) / N`)

Comment: Yup, I actually just did that :)

Comment: Note: `numOfLines()` is a off-by-1 problem when the last _line_ lacks a `'\n'`.

Comment: Tip: Even if row and column count are the same value, use 2 different variables  like `Msize_row, Msize_col` for the following code loops.  Easier to understand and avoid errors.